# Older git commits don't have user.name and user.email. How do I change that?

Tags: git, github

I was working in a private repository of an organization. The commits that I was making were not being linked with my user name. I checked `git config --list`. There was no row for `user.name` and `user.email`. I have now added the 2 rows. And now my commits are linked to my github profile as expected.

I want to link my older commits also to my github profile. How do I do so?

Edit: I already saw the question mentioned as [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-to-change-the-author-and-committer-name-and-e-mail-of-multiple-commits-in-gi). This did not help. As there was no field named `user.email` in the older commits. And the older and the new email are the same. I tried to run the script. But it did not work out.

Comment: Were you the only one committing to that repository or are there other authors?

Comment: There was one more.